# Eclipse: included Feature not showing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

In my RCP application I have a main Feature added to the Debug Configuration Plug-ins dependecies. This Feature contains a couple of plugins but it also has another feature included in it. The problem is that this 'child' feature is not activated unless I add it to the Debug Config. as well. I only want my main Feature to be added to the dependencies thought. How can I make this work ?

Comment: Does your main feature list the second feature in the Dependencies 'Required Features/Plug-ins' list of the feature.xml editor?

Comment: @greg-449 Hello Greg. Indeed, it wasn't added to the Dependencies. I added it but unfortunately it's still not working :(

Comment: Looking at it again if this your feature it probably should be in 'Included Features' rather than 'Dependencies'. What does the Run Configuration 'Validate Plugins' button say?

Comment: @greg-449 the plugins are always validated. with or without the secondary feature